# Element inherits wrong style

Tags: css

I have a huge amount of elements in my website... And since I added the following css... Some elements inherit from these css styles... While they don't have anything to do with it: other scope, no direct definition to the css style etc... What am I doing wrong?

```
#InformationForDiv
{
    width: 205px;
    height: 180px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 35px 0 35px;
    text-align: center;
}

#InformationForDiv ul
{
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0px;
    display:block;
}

#InformationForDiv li
{
    border-bottom: solid 1px #D6D6D6;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: block;
}

#InformationForDiv p
{
     display:inline;
     float:right;
     margin:0;
     text-align:right;
     font-size: 16px;
     color: #B02229;
}


#InformationForDiv li a:link, a:visited
{
    color: #544B42;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}

#InformationForDiv li a:hover
{
   color: #544B42;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #544B42;
   font-size: 12px;
}

#InformationForDiv li a:visited
{
   color: #544B42;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 12px;
}

#InformationForDiv img
{
    margin: 10px 0 5px 0;
}
```

Comment: If you would include some of the HTML code and show which elements are displayed wrongly it would be easier to answer your question.

Comment: you should add some other data. The css looks good to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least this one:

```
#InformationForDiv li a:link, a:visited
```

will select all `a:visited` elements and it doesn't look like your intention.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps because those elements have an ancestor in the HTML document in which they exist that has the ID "InformationForDiv".

Its generally not a good idea to include in an external css selectors the use of specific element IDs.  External CSS ought to rely on class names to select appropriate elements.

Comment: There are many key reasons why a web developer would give an element an ID. There is only one key reason to place a class name on an element. An external css can expect to be shared by multiple pages. A developer of one those pages shouldn't have to worry about IDs already used by other pages that are then styled by the css using # in selectors. An should be ID is unique in a document by allowing selectors in shared css to use them then those ID gain a greater possibly unintended wider scope.

Comment: That may mean two things - you suggest not to style based on id or embed styles with id-based selectors in the page. Which is yours? While what you're saying does apply to some sitewide stylesheets I see absolutely no reason to be dogmatic about it — to me it's just one of those universal rules that are all wrong (including the one I've just declared).

Comment: @Hacker: Many specification documents use two similar but different terms "SHOULD" and "MUST".  I used the term "SHOULD". In my actual answer I use the terms "generally" and "ought".  I can't see why you see that as "dogmatic".  A website wide CSS is implied in the  language of the OP question and that was what I was addressing.

Comment: AnthonyWJones, Perhaps I perceived it as a stronger statement because it struck me a bit out place as an answer to original question. But indeed, upon closer inspection I have to admit your wording is not half as strong as I've thought it is.